# Display a customer ad in iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, popup, app-store

We'd like to display our own customers' ads in our iOS App. Do you think Apple tolerates it?

Like if we'd advertise a canadian mobile carrier ou something? I had one app rejected lately - Lost a lot of time and money so I don't want to end up with nothing again. I checked in the documentations but haven't found anything.

The concept would be popping up an ad when the user clicks on a list item, before the download of the associated file (mp3). I think they might find it "invasive" behavior or something. So if you have any informations, I'd be more than happy to read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is allowed by Apple to use your own/customer advertisements and shouldn't endanger the approval of your application by Apple.